# How to select only values without characters in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have Pandas DataFrame like below, "col1" is string data type:

```
col1
----
123D
2222CCA123
DRftu22876
12345
```

And I would like to select only rows where value is without charaters, so as a result i need something like below:

```
col1
-----
12345
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: `df[df['col1'].str.match('^\d+$')]` ?

Comment: `df[df['col1'].str.isdigit()]`

Comment: SomeDude it is ok,and how can I do that in vice versa, so select only values with characters ?

Comment: @ratus111 try:  `df[df['col1'].str.match('^\D+$')]` for values with characters only and no digits

Comment: `df[~df['col1'].str.isdigit()]` is the inverse of DarryIG's answer~

Answer (score 2):

Just for some variety, a non-`str` based way. Here I try to convert the value to a number, and then use whether or not that conversion worked:

```
print(df[pd.to_numeric(df.col1, errors='coerce').isna()])
print(df[pd.to_numeric(df.col1, errors='coerce').nota()])
```

Outputs:

```
         col1
0        123D
1  2222CCA123
2  DRftu22876

    col1
3  12345
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regular expression` to get only values what you want.

In Pandas, you can use `regular expression` in various ways, as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1': [
            '123D',
            '2222CCA123',
            'DRftu22876',
            '12345',
            'abCdeF',
            'ABCDEf',
        ]
    }
)
print(df)
#          col1
# 0        123D
# 1  2222CCA123
# 2  DRftu22876
# 3       12345
```

- Using `contains` function

```py
# Using contains function
df1 = df[df['col1'].str.contains('^[0-9]+$', regex=True)]
print(df1)
#     col1
# 3  12345
```

- Using `match` function

```py
# Using match function
df2 = df[df['col1'].str.match('^[0-9]+$')]
print(df2)
#     col1
# 3  12345
```

The matching pattern can be varied. There are more ways to fileter digit only values.

If you want to get only character values, you can changed the matching patterns, as follows;

```py
# Using contains function
df1 = df[df['col1'].str.contains('^[^0-9]+$', regex=True)]  # or '^[a-zA-Z]+$'  # or '^[a-zA-Z]+$' instead of '^[^0-9]+$'
print(df1)
# 4  abCdeF
# 5  ABCDEf

# Using match function
df2 = df[df['col1'].str.match('^[^0-9]+$')]  # or '^[a-zA-Z]+$' instead of '^[^0-9]+$'
print(df2)
# 4  abCdeF
# 5  ABCDEf
```

To get more knowledge about `regular expression` and get another patter of values, please refer to https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/regex

Comment: Park could you make it also in other way to stay only values with characters without numbers ?

Comment: @ratus111 I added the examples :)